# Why is there read SCSI command during a sys_write()

Tags: linux, io, device-driver, scsi

I want to understand how a `sys_write` on a scsi device works. Therefore I wrote a simple test program, and added in the `issue` function of the device driver some debug `printk()` to print the `ata_queued_cmd->scsicmd->cmnd`.

```c
int main() {
    int w;
    char buffer[512] = "test string with 512 byte";

    // OPEN
    int fd = open("/dev/sdd", O_WRONLY | O_SYNC);

    // WRITE
    w = write(fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));

    return 0;
}
```

In `/var/log/messages` I can see the following issued commands:

```
  scsicmd->cmnd
------------------------------
 0x28 | READ(10)
 0x2A | WRITE(10)
 0x35 | SYNCHRONIZE CACHE (10)
```

The 512 Byte I want to write should be the blocksize. This is how I get this value:

```bsh
root$ blockdev --getsize /dev/sdd # returns size in sectors
488397168
root$ blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdd # returns size in sectors
250059350016
root$ python -c "print 250059350016.0/488397168"
512.0
```

It's very important for me, that the data is power-failure safe written. That's the reason why I want to wait for the reuturn with `O_SYNC`. Now I have some questions:

- Why is there a `READ` before the `WRITE`?
- Does the `SYNCHRONIZE CACHE` guarantee me, if the data is in the internal cache of the drive? Or is there more I could do to have a secure write?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out now. They read it to load the data into an internal Kernel buffer, so when you have multiple writes/reads, the data is already buffered.